# Se puede manipular la salida hdmi con java?

Tags: java

Lo que quiero hacer es desde una aplicación generar imágenes y verlas en una tv conectada a la pc por hdmi, la idea es que por la tv no se vea la interfaz de la aplicación ni la interfaz del sistema operativo, sino, sólo la imagen que creé.

No busco una solución para la app, pero una forma de presentar mis imágenes en pantalla completa por la salida hdmi.

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Creo que lo que pides es un poco amplio. ¿Qué has buscado y qué has intentado?

Comment: Me tomé la libertad de clarificar que estas buscando una solución para el problema de pantalla completa, no para la app que estas construyendo. Espero que eso te mantiene la pregunta abierta. Si me equivoqué, saca la edición no más.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias! Buen aporte!

Comment: @Andrew, probé con el conjunto de clases `GraphicsEnvironment`, tal vez cuando leíste la consulta no estaba muy clara, @Stefan Nolde le añadió algo extra para clarificarla, busco simplemente manipular la salida hdmi con java, desde que conectás un dispositivo, detectar lo que conectaste y mostrar lo que quiera, una imagen por ejemplo, espero haber sido claro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generalmente la capa de hardware no importa mucho a Java (el grado de abstracción es tal cual la fuerza y la debilidad de Java), así según yo la mejor forma sería una aplicación que muestra lo que quieres mostrar en pantalla completa y dejar la manera como el SO se conecta con el dispositivo al SO.

Para recorrer las pantallas disponibles (en el caso que tienes una pantalla conectada al hdmi) te debería servir:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsDevice[] gs = ge.getScreenDevices();
```

Luego para poner el dispositivo de tu elección en modo pantalla completa puedes usar el [modo exclusivo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html):

```
GraphicsDevice miDispositivo=gs[miSeleccion];
Window miVentana;

try {
    miDispositivo.setFullScreenWindow(miVentana);
    ...
} finally {
    miDispositivo.setFullScreenWindow(null);
}
```

Comment: Si, es justo el conjunto de clases que utilizo, y es por el camino que estoy yendo ahora, realmente buscaba que la aplicación se encargue de todo y que el usuario final no tenga que configurar algo extra por fuera de la aplicación, probablemente para hacer esto tenga que buscar algo de más bajo nivel... De todas maneras muchas gracias y pienso que me va a ser de mucha utilidad esa data sobre el modo exclusivo, muchas gracias!